# Java PKCS11 with iaik

Tags: java, applet, smartcard, pkcs#11

I created an applet using the `iaik libraries` it works perfectly in my applet viewer but in my web browser I get this:  trusted loader attempted to load sandboxed resource any idea ?

Amm ok so I got it to work but I would like to also know why ... I am using netbeans ... after I set the option for self signed I compiled and in my dist folder it created a jar file with my classes...after that I copied my jar file, libs ...etc. to the folder with my applet ... and ran it ... so what does the sandbox ment and how come I do not get it anymore... I also copied that PKCS11Wrapper to my jdk/bin folder....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems is appear because your applet tried to access to native library and your applet has to be signed, BUT you've written that you sign it, so, if you place the code in the jre/lib/ext directory, signing the code is not required, try to create console application from applet and try to start it. I think you will see that all is work , and your IDE signature is not working. [How to start applet from main method](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/TurningAnApplet/)

Comment: Thank you very much so ...  I managed to fix it but now I get this trusted loader attempted to load sandboxed resource I have to mention that iaik uses a dll wrapper

Comment: @cataHHH, using a browser with an Applet to load a `.dll` is a *very* *very* (*very*) error prone method, and I should stay clear of it. And yes, I did program something similar once. It worked, but after that I've always been in favour of "thick clients" over frickin' hacks like that.